# Save radio button state w/button in Fragment and load upon opening app

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, radio-group

So I am creating an app where when you first open it you have the option to use WiFi or Data to retrieve the data with oAuth2 (Still need to figure this out). However, I also have a settings button in my Nav Drawer that has a radio group with an enable or disable as far as using data. If the person says to enable Data, I turn their WiFi off (I shouldn't do this) I should be checking for connection state and whenever the connection equals Mobile Data then start uploading and if they click disable check for when the connection is WiFi and start uploading. However, I don't know how to do that currently so unless someone smarter than me can let me know now, that is how it is.

However, I am having an issue with my onClick on the save button saving the button state and then loading that state/decision upon opening the app. Furthermore, it is set as disabled by default, however, if the user clicks "Use Cell" in the app start up pop up, I would like to change that value.

I would really prefer some help in learning how to do this stuff, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    EditText emailText;
    TextView responseView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    static final String API_KEY = "USE_YOUR_OWN_API_KEY";
    static final String API_URL = "https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/person.json?";
    static final String ClientId= "";
    static final String ClientSecret = "";
    static final String SCOPE = "";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        responseView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseView);
        emailText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailText);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        final Context context = this;
        Button queryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.queryButton);
        queryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, NavDrawerActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        WifivsDataDialog myDiag = new WifivsDataDialog();
        //myDiag.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog_layout");
        myDiag.setCancelable(false);

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean dontShowDialog = sharedPref.getBoolean("DONT_SHOW_DIALOG", false);
        if (!dontShowDialog) {
            new WifivsDataDialog().show(getFragmentManager(), "WiFi");
        }

    }





    private int checkAvailableConnectionType() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        int type = activeNetwork.getType();
        if(activeNetwork.isConnected() && (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE ||
                type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)) {
            return type;
        }
        return -1;
    }


    class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private Exception exception;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            responseView.setText("");
        }

        protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
            String email = emailText.getText().toString();
            // Do some validation here

            try {
                URL url = new URL(API_URL + "email=" + email + "&apiKey=" + API_KEY);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                try {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    return stringBuilder.toString();
                }
                finally{
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            if(response == null) {
                response = "THERE WAS AN ERROR";
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.i("INFO", response);
            responseView.setText(response);
            // TODO: check this.exception
            // TODO: do something with the feed

//            try {
//                JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
//                String requestID = object.getString("requestId");
//                int likelihood = object.getInt("likelihood");
//                JSONArray photos = object.getJSONArray("photos");
//                .
//                .
//                .
//                .
//            } catch (JSONException e) {
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code that controls the app startup dialog.

```
public class WifivsDataDialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private CheckBox checkBox;
    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_box_layout, container);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) mainView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        button1 = (Button) mainView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) mainView.findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                // Store the isChecked to Preference here
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("DONT_SHOW_DIALOG", isChecked);
                editor.commit();

            }
        });
        return mainView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                // Do wifi stuff here

                    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);

                    dismiss();
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                // Do cellular stuff here
                ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                Boolean isConnected = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnected();
                if(isConnected == true)
                {
                    dismiss();
                }else
                {
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();

                    alertDialog.setTitle("Info");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Mobile Data is not turned on. Please turn Mobile Data on to continue.");
                    alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //dismiss();
                            Intent intentSettings = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(intentSettings);
                        }
                    });

                    alertDialog.show();
                }

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code settingsfragment.java

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment
{
    View myView;
    Button button;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_layout, container, false);
        button= (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button3);


        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) myView .findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // checkedId is the RadioButton selected

                switch(checkedId) {
                    case R.id.radioButton7:
                        // switch to fragment 1
                        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                        Boolean isConnected = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnected();
                        if(isConnected != true)
                        {
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();

                            alertDialog.setTitle("Info");
                            alertDialog.setMessage("Mobile Data is not turned on. Please turn Mobile Data on to continue.");
                            alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    //dismiss();
                                    Intent intentSettings = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
                                    startActivity(intentSettings);
                                }
                            });

                            alertDialog.show();
                        }
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioButton6:
                        // Fragment 2
                        WifiManager wifiManager1 = (WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                        wifiManager1.setWifiEnabled(true);

                        break;
                }
            }
            public void onClick(View v) {
                private void saveGenderInPreference () {
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                    RadioGroup radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
                    int selectedId = radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    if (selectedId == R.id.radioButton7)
                        editor.putBoolean("is_Wifi", true);
                    else
                        editor.putBoolean("is_Wifi", false);

                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
        });

        return myView;
    }
}
```

Comment: check sharedprefrences. You can store button state as boolean and when activity or frag opens based on that boolean enalbe or disable the button.

Comment: Right, but I have that at the bottom of my last piece of code but still nothing.

Comment: In the last piece of code you are saving `is_wifi` into the SharedPreferences, but in your onCreate you are looking up `DONT_SHOW_DIALOG` in `sharedPref.getBoolean("DONT_SHOW_DIALOG", false);` - are you looking up the `is_wifi` value anywhere?

Comment: And why do you have a function called `saveGenderInPreference ()` in your `onClick`? If you want to call this "helper" method inside your `onClick` handler, then you need to declare the function OUTSIDE `public void onClick(View v)`.

Comment: The don't show dialog is for my check box. And because I want to save whichever they pick with that button. Disregard the naming for the moment, just a random piece a put there from some other code.

Comment: So I could do boolean WiFiPicked = sharedPref.getBoolean("if-wifi", false);
        if (!WiFiPicked) { use mobile data, whatever the code would be for that} all within that shared preference in my mainactivity?

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla any ideas?

Comment: You are right, you should do something like `sharedPref.getBoolean("is_wifi", false);` - and you do this preferably in the `onCreate` of `MainActivity`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120838/discussion-between-ishmaelmakitla-and-james-robert-singleton).

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla I sent you a message.